# How do I change the property of an enum with Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I need to hide some menu options in the production environment, but not in development.

I implemented this as an enum like this:

```
public enum Functionality {
    FUNCTION_1(true),
    FUNCTION_2,
    FUNCTION_3(true);

    private boolean usable;

    Functionality() {
        this(false);
    }

    Functionality(boolean usable) {
        this.usable = usable;
    }

    public boolean isUsable() {
        return usable;
    }
}
```

And then, when I need to show the menu options, I check whether that functionality needs to be shown.

So I need to be able to change the usable boolean when the environment is development. But I cannot find any way to do it in Spring.

Do you know of a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* change the fields of an `enum`, but it's usually considered a bad idea and is often a design smell.

A better approach would possibly be to not have `usable` be a field at all, instead make it a calculated property:

```
public enum Functionality {
    FUNCTION_1(true),
    FUNCTION_2,
    FUNCTION_3(true);

    private final boolean restricted;

    Functionality() {
       this(false);
    }

    Functionality(boolean restricted) {
        this.restricted = restricted;
    }

    public boolean isRestricted() {
        return restricted;
    }

    public boolean isUsable() {
        if (!restricted) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return SystemConfiguration.isDevelopmentSystem();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously there would need to be a method like `SystemConfiguration.isDevelopmentSystem()` for this to work.

In some systems I implemented I used another `enum` for this:

```
public enum SystemType {
    PRODUCTION,
    TESTING,
    DEVELOPMENT;

    public final SystemType CURRENT;

    static {
        String type = System.getEnv("system.type");
        if ("PROD".equals(type)) {
            CURRENT = PRODUCTION;
        } else if ("TEST".equals(type)) {
            CURRENT = TESTING;
        } else {
            CURRENT = DEVELOPMENT;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I used a system property to specify the type at runtime, but any other configuration type might be just as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

enums are essentially constants. With the hard-coding of `true` to `FUNCTION_1` and `FUNCTION_3`, there isn't a way that Spring can inject anything.

This is a duplicate of:
[Using Spring IoC to set up enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710392/using-spring-ioc-to-set-up-enum-values)

Answer (score -1):

java enums are singleton and immutable, so I dont think you can change enum state anyway.

Comment: Nothing in the language specifies that `enum` values must be immutable. It's a good design decision and generally accepted best practice, but not required.

Comment: You can definitely change the state of an enum. You just need to add a setUsable method to the code above.

Comment: @ Joachim Sauer & @Thijs Wouters: Sorry for the misundestanding, as enums are singleton, its best to have it immutable.