# Injecting MessageSource into an Enum

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

I am trying to use an ENUM for a form:select as such:

```
<form:select path="myEnum">
  <form:options itemLabel="resourceBundleLabel" />
</form:select>
```

With an Enum that looks something like:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  ONE("rb.one"), TWO("rb.two");

  private MessageSource messageSource;

  private String rbKey;

  public String getResourceBundleLabel() {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    Locale locale = request.getLocale();
    return messageSource.getMessage(this.rbKey, null, locale);
  }

  public MyEnum(String rbKey) {
    this.rbKey = rbKey;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to get the MessageSource injected.  I tried adding @Component and @Autowired (got an error because there was no default constructor.  I then tried switching @Component to @Configurable.  Then I tried removing both annotation, and implementing MessageSourceAware.  In all cases, the messageSource is null when I get inside the getResourceBundleLable().

Ultimately, what I am trying to accomplish is to build out the select options using an Enum, but make it such that is uses the proper Resource Bundle and local.  Am I just wasting my time on something that is not feasible?

Comment: I would suggest you store, at most, only the message code in your enum. Your current design couples your enum very closely to a servlet environment - what if you wanted to use this enum elsewhere in the future?

Comment: I would like that approach, but the Spring form:options does not allow me to set the label using a resource bundle.  The only way I can see to do it is to resolve the message key in the Enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710392/using-spring-ioc-to-set-up-enum-values/16739628#16739628) for how to inject dependencies into enums with minimal plumbing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710392/using-spring-ioc-to-set-up-enum-values/29143035#29143035). It doesn't not inject it but use it as a static method.