# Inject Dependency Value Into Enum

Tags: java, dependency-injection, enums, spring-boot

I have the following enum:

```
public class Wrapper(){
    public enum MyEnum{
        A("a_id", "a_source", "a_target"),
        B("b_id", "b_source", "b_target"),
        ...
        Z("z_id", "z_source", "z_target"),

        String id;
        String source;
        String target;
        myEnum(String i, String s, String t){
            id = i;
            source = s;
            target = t;
        }
    }    
}
```

If possible I would like to be able to specify the enum parameters (e.g. `"a_id"`) in `application.properties` so that I can modify them and inject them in as needed. I was initially thinking of something like:

```
public class Wrapper(){
    @Value("${a.id}")
    private String A_ID;
    @Value("${a.source}")
    private String A_SOURCE;
    @Value("${a.target}")
    private String A_TARGET;

    public enum MyEnum{
        A(A_ID, A_SOURCE, A_TARGET),
        ...
    }    
}
```

with `application.properties` looking like:

```
a.id=a_id
a.source=a_source
a.target=a_target
```

The problem is that I cannot call `A_ID` inside the enum without making it `static` but if I make it `static` I cannot perform dependency injection (from my understanding).

What would be the best approach to having those strings externally configurable and injected in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly this guy has the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/711022/4546150

As dnault said, trying to get configuration values from `application.properties` wont be possible with Spring - you would need to guarantee that Spring has loaded and parsed the configuration, then try to inject it into a static object.

But, as the SO post I linked mentions - do you *need* to use Springs configuration loading for this? I believe [Resource Bundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) was mentioned as an alternative:

```
public enum MyEnum {
A;

public final String id;
public final String source;
public final String target;

MyEnum() {
    this.id = BUNDLE.getString("A.id");
    this.source = BUNDLE.getString("A.source");
    this.target = BUNDLE.getString("A.target");
}

private static final ResourceBundle BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. But you can have:

```
public enum MyEnum {
     A, B, C, .... Z;

     String idKey() { return name().toLowerCase() + ".id"; }
     String sourceKey() { return name().toLowerCase() + ".source"; }
     String targetKey() { return name().toLowerCase() + ".target"; }

};
```

Then you can have property file as you've define and then somewhere in the client code:

```
MyEnum e = ...
properties.getProperty(e.idKey());
```